# Chamisha Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaakov went down to Mitzrayim 115 years after Avraham died.

Avraham was 100 when Yitzchak was born, 60 years later Yaakov was born.  Avraham died 15 years later at 175.  Yaakov was 130 when he descended to Mitzrayim.